# Compare time in php not working

Tags: php, date

```
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $plusfive = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." +5 minutes"));

    if ( $plusfive > $now ) { 
        echo "correct"; 
    }
    else { 
        echo "nope"; 
    };
```

I want to count up 5 minutes to the current time so i can post $plusfive to mysql and when that time has past then the user will be able to click on the button again.
But if i try to see if the time ($plusfive) i bigger then the current time it says nope. How can I do this?

Comment: The above code works fine for me. I get "correct".

Comment: You should compare timestamps or DateTime objects, not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
if ( strtotime($plusfive) > strtotime($now) ) { 
    echo "correct"; 
}
else { 
    echo "nope"; 
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this". A good answer will have an explanation of what was done and why. This helps to the OP to understand as well as future visitors to Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks man that worked :D need to wait some minutes to aprove your aswer.

Comment: @Rizier123 Agreed and often ignored (as to this time also). Imagine all those juicy upvotes it would have gotten? But then again, I don't think they care for it much, "they" meaning "all involved parties" ;-) Pfftt... what can you do when you live a shoe(?).